# mongoengine ReferenceField mongoengine.errors.ValidationError

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-login

Need your help. I try to work with mongoengine, flask, flask-login.

My model:

```
class Post(db.Document):
   text = db.StringField(max_length=240)
   pub_date = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
   author = db.ReferenceField(Member)
```

And I get current user (flask-login):

```
from flask.ext.login import current_user
```

Than in views.py:

```
new_post = Post()
    new_post.text = 'bla-bla'
    #new_post.author = current_user                                 #- DON`T WORK
    new_post.author = Member.objects.get(id=current_user.id)        #-WORK (WHY?)
    new_post.save()
```

What wrong in `new_post.author = current_user` if `new_post.author = Member.objects.get(id=current_user.id)` - work okay.

If try with `new_post.author = current_user` - get error:

```
mongoengine.errors.ValidationError
ValidationError: ValidationError (Post:None) (A ReferenceField only accepts DBRef or documents: ['author'])
```

Thx, people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These errors happen because `current_user` has the [LocalProxy](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/local.py#L250) type, while mongo is looking for a reference. While `current_user` in many ways works the same way as the actual `Member` object it proxies for, it can't be used as a reference because there is no information about the reference collection for mongo to use as a DBRef.

If you want to avoid Member.objects.get(id=current_user.id) to get the actual object, you can just get the get the actual `Member` object from `current_user`:

```
new_post.author = current_user._get_current_object()
```

or just the `DBRef`:

```
new_post.author = current_user.to_dbref()
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for asking this here.. but I am using this approach and keep getting InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <User: User object>. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: @LarissaLeite A very large number of things. I'd recommend creating a new question with samples of your code so we can better help :-)

Comment: Actually I did, if you could please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32746284/invaliddocument-cannot-encode-object-user-user-object-referencefield-with-m