# InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <User: User object> ReferenceField with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I've been working with Flask and MongoEngine, and I am having trouble when trying to save an object because of a ReferenceField.

This is what my model looks like:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Document):
    first_name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    last_name = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255)

class Post(db.Document):
    description = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    inserted_at = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
    tags = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Tag'))
    comments = db.ListField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'))
    user = db.ReferenceField('User')
```

This is how I create the Post object:

```
    user = User.objects.filter(id=current_user.id).first()

    post = Post(
        description = request.json["description"],
        user = user
    )
```

I have also tried:

```
user = current_user._get_current_object()
```

But I keep getting:

```
InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: <User: User object>
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some issue with the db module you are using. Is it really the mongoengine module. Because your code works fine, if I use

```
import mongoengine as db
```

Comment: db is create like this: 
app.config.from_object('config')
db = MongoEngine(app).. no idea what can be wrong with this module :(

Comment: I haven't actually tested it in flask, but it works perfectly in django app with mongoengine

Comment: I've deleted all db. in my models (I added from mongoenine import *), but I still get the same thing..

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is from a long time, but I got the same problem. I don't know if it's for different reasons, but the context does look very similar.

Anyway, it looks like the `current_user` object is a `LocalProxy` instance which does not play well with mongoengine. The trick was to "force" dereference the ObjectID of the instance, like this:

```
post = Post(
        description = request.json["description"],
        user = user.id
    )
```